# a solution for filtering some rows of data based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I have the following example data, and I'd like to filter a piece of data, when **(col1 = 'A' and col2 = '0')** we want to keep rows until next **(col1 = 'A')**.
I want to do using pandas dataframe but I don't know how it is.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],  'col2': [0, 1]})
```

For example, we have this data

```
col1 col2
 A    0
 C
 A    1 
 B
 C
 A    1 
 B
 B
 C
 A    0 
 B 
 C
 A    1 
 B 
 C
 C
```

The result I want to achieve is:

```
col1 col2 
 A    0 
 C 
 A    0 
 B 
 C
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We first [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) row blocks starting with `'A'` and then propagate the first value of `col2` to all rows of the group. From this result we take all rows with `0` in `col2`.

```
 df[df.groupby(df.col1.eq('A').cumsum()).col2.transform('first').eq(0)]
```

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('ACABCABBCABCABCC'),
                   'col2': [0, None, 1, None, None, 1, None, None, None, 0, None, None, 1, None, None, None]}
                 ).astype({'col2': 'Int32'})
```

Result:

```
   col1  col2
0     A     0
1     C  <NA>
9     A     0
10    B  <NA>
11    C  <NA>
```

Comment: Nice answer @Stef